# InnerHtml and InnerText ASPX doesn work

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a aspx file wich contain:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <div>
        <table border = "2" id ="pcInfo" >
            <tr><td>bla bla</td><td><span id = "idex" runat ="server"></span>  </td></tr>..
```

The data in table is introduced using Javascript  and/or JScript.
In C# code, when I try to mail this data using :

```
a = ".." + idex.InnerHtml.ToString() + "..";<br />
b = "-" + idex.InnerText.ToString() + "-";
```

a is always "...." and b is always "--". The assignation is done in click method of a button, so after all elements of table/span have some content. How can I get the content? and where to place code?

**Solutin**

Content generated with Javascript can be taken just if for display are used input fields.

Comment: Please can you post your complete javascript code and your MVC controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

`InnerHtml` will get inner html of the tag and in your question you are getting InnerHtml of span `<span id = "idex" runat ="server"></span>` but there is nothing inside the tag so thats why it will return nothing. let suppose i want   and inner html of table so i will do something

```
<div id = "idex" runat ="server">
          <table border = "2"  >
                <tr ><td >bla bla</td><td><span>asdfasdf</span></td></tr>

             </table>
 </div>
```

i used div because you cannot get innerhtml of table so in code behind

```
var html= idex.InnerHtml;
```

now it will return everything in div

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from question you are trying to access span tag value in your code behind. you can get span tag text from both "InnerHtml" and "InnerText".

Here is tested code of .aspx and its .cs file for same.

Default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <table border = "2" id ="pcInfo" >
            <tr><td></td><td><span id = "idex" runat ="server">my content</span></td></tr>

      </table>
        Inner Html= <asp:Label ID="lblSpanInnerHtml" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        Inner Text= <asp:Label ID="lblSpanInnerText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblSpanInnerHtml.Text = idex.InnerHtml;
            lblSpanInnerText.Text = idex.InnerText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem extends from a misunderstanding of the request-response process. Only form elements are posted back to the server. Asp.net webforms get fancy and maintains some state info in a hidden form field called `ViewState`.

Anything dynamically added to non-form elements via javascript are essentially invisible to the server side code. You need another way to transfer that data back to the server. The easiest way to do this is to also populate that data into a hidden form element and retrieve that value server side.

E.g.

```
<tr><td></td><td>
    <span id = "idex" runat ="server">my content</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnIdx" value="my content">
</td></tr>
```

Then you populate the hidden field by modifying your existing javascript.

Then serverside get the value

```
lblSpanInnerText.Text = idex.Value;
```